# Here maps - how to move and animate a marker to new location along with zoom

Tags: javascript

I am using here maps in order to show a route from point A to point B.

Now I am trying to add a marker and update its position from a websocket, I used the Geovisualization to move the marker following this https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/geovisualization/technology_animation/animated-markers
(I dont really know if it is the right way to do it, but it is working)

I can see the marker moving from position A to position B and so on, but the client wants to see the marker always on center of the map.

How can I move and zoom the map with the marker?

I tried to create a group with the marker's new position and then get the bounds of it but it zooms in too fast:

```
let marker = new H.map.DomMarker({ lat: data[0][1], lng: data[0][2] });
    let group = new H.map.Group();
    group.addObject(marker);
    map.setViewBounds(group.getBounds(), true);
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 2):

Try using the setPosition to set the new position of the marker on the map

```
const marker = H.map.Marker({ lat: number; lng: number }, { icon: icon });
marker.setPosition({ lat: number, lng: number });
```

To center the map on the marker position try using setCenter and setZoom, where the second parameter in the setCenter and setZoom is to determine whether it should animate or not.

```
const isMapAnimated: boolean = true;
map.setCenter({ lat: number; lng: number }, isMapAnimated);
map.setZoom(16, isMapAnimated);
```

Comment: I was having the same requirement as mentioned above and the solution is perfect. But while map is moving, it kind of goes off and then on. For a second map is blank and then comes back with the updated position. By default i kept animation flag true. Please suggest